# Probability that $\displaystyle \vert x\vert +\vert y\vert +\vert z\vert +\vert x+y+z\vert=\vert x+y\vert +\vert x+z\vert +\vert y+z\vert$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, coordinate-systems, 3d

> Real numbers $x, y$, and $z$ are chosen from the interval $[−1, 1]$ independently and uniformly at random.
>   What is the probability that $$\vert x\vert +\vert y\vert +\vert z\vert +\vert x+y+z\vert=\vert x+y\vert +\vert x+z\vert +\vert y+z\vert$$

Now if all of $x, y, z$ are positive or all negative then the equation is of course satisfied.  Hence if we consider a 3D space , it denotes two unit cubes, one in the first octant centred at $\left( \frac 12,\frac 12,\frac 12\right)$ and the other in seventh octant centred at $\left( -\frac 12,-\frac 12,-\frac 12\right)$.

The total measure of universal set is the cube with edge length $2$ centred at origin.

But now I have a problem about what if any two of $x, y, z$ are positive while the other remaining be negative or the other way around.  Even if I try to make cases it seems to be quite a cumbersome task to approach since we will also need to check signs of $\vert x+y\vert$ and similarly others as well as that of $\vert x+y+z\vert $

I also thought to give a shot using vectors but didn't reach any specific result.

Any help would be quite beneficial.

Edit:

I would also be happy to see a geometrical intuitive way to attack the problem.

Comment: I have to admit nothing comes quickly to mind.  I did a quick simulation, and the probability (assuming I haven't made any mistakes) comes out to something close to $0.3489$.  Doesn't ring any bells yet.  I'll keep thinking about it.  Interesting problem.

Comment: @BrianTung Thanks and by the way the answer is $3/8$ as stated by my professor.

Comment: Weird.  I must have done something wrong.  Let me make sure I've picked the right PRNG.

Comment: @Digamma:  you could have your simulation print out (some of the) points where the signs disagree but the equation is satisfied.  That might give some inspiration.

Comment: @Digamma: Yeah, it was all roundoff error.  I get $3/8$ now, too.

Comment: There is a natural $n$-d generalization (even length sums = odd length sums), and the 4-d probability is 13/48.  As in the 3-d case, the measure in two orthants is 1, and the measure in all others is 1/6.  My simple symbolic integration routine crashed Mathematica for the 5-d case, however.

Comment: @Jim Ferry I myself was working on generalization on n dimensional space but was way beyond the scope for a 17 year old like me.

Comment: @Jim Ferry Probability for 5-d would have been quite helpful to predict the generalized explicit formula for the probability in n dimensional space

Comment: I did a simulation in Matlab for 5-d.  I got a success of 12707907 out of 1e8 for orthants with two negative numbers, and 15419325 out of 1e8 for orthants with one negative number.

Comment: How did this problem come about?  Is it just a question from your professor?  Does your professor have any notions about a general expression?

Comment: @Brian Tung I don't think so.  He said it was from some mathematics competition and found the question amazing so he thought to share it with us.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are positive and consider the possible values of $z$. Because $|x|+|y|=|x+y|$ here, we want the equation
$$
   |z| + |x+y+z| = |x+z| + |y+z|
$$
to hold.

Assume $x \le y$; in this case, we have $z \le x+z \le y+z \le x+y+z$, and so we can consider five possibilities based on which of these are positive.

1. $0 \le z \le x+z \le y+z \le x+y+z$. Then the equation holds. You already know this case.
2. $z \le 0 \le x+z \le y+z \le x+y+z$. Then the equation simplifies to $x+y=x+y+2z$, which has probability $0$.
3. $z \le x+z \le 0 \le y+z \le x+y+z$. Then the equation simplifies to $x+y=y-x$, which has probability $0$.
4. $z \le x+z \le y+z \le 0 \le x+y+z$. Then the equation simplifies to $x+y = -x-y-2z$, which has probability $0$.
5. $z \le x+z \le y+z \le x+y+z \le 0$. Then the equation holds. This case is new.

The same thing happens when $x \ge y$, so that doesn't need to be considered separately.

So we see that when $x$ and $y$ are positive, we want either $z$ to be positive as well, or we want $x+y+z$ to be negative.

By symmetry, this covers all the possibilities. The equation holds when:

- All three of $x,y,z$ are positive;
- Two of $x,y,z$ are positive, but $x+y+z$ is negative;
- Two of $x,y,z$ are negative, but $x+y+z$ is positive;
- All three of $x,y,z$ are negative.

The regions inside $[-1,1]^3$ where these hold have volume respectively:

- $1$ (it's a cube of side length $1$);
- $\frac12$ (it's three pyramids that form a corner of a cube with $\frac16$ the volume);
- $\frac12$;
- $1$.

So total volume $3$ (out of $8$), so the equation holds with probability $\frac38$.

Comment: Can you try to generalize it for n-dimensional space please?

Comment: Not with the same approach; the amount of casework grows exponentially.

Answer (score 3):

A simulation using R statistical software, for those interested, agrees with the theoretical answer.

```
> x<-runif(10^7,-1,1)
> y<-runif(10^7,-1,1)
> z<-runif(10^7,-1,1)
> mean(abs(x)+abs(y)+abs(z)+abs(x+y+z)==abs(x+y)+abs(x+z)+abs(y+z))
[1] 0.3749906
```

Answer (score 0):

The following simulation in Matlab gives simulated probabilities, $10^7$ results for n from 2 to 10.  Things written after percent signs are comments.

> for n=2:10    % dimension n
>     b=cell(1,n);
>     [b{:}]=ndgrid(0:1);  % n different 2x2x2x...x2 arrays
>     A=cat(20,b{:});
>     B=reshape(A,2^n,n);  %  array contains 0s and 1s to define all 2^n sums
>     C=(-1).^sum(B,2);  % array contains +1 or -1 for each sum
>     for m=1:10000   % 10000 times 1000 trials is 10^7
>       D=(2*rand(1000,n)-1)*B';  % 1000 trials, all 2^n sums
>       E=abs(D)*C;  % all 1000 combined sums
>       k(n)=k(n)+sum(abs(E)<1e-8);  % count combined sums =0, give or take underflow
>     end;
>     disp(num2str([n k(n)/10000000]));
>     end;

```
2.0000    0.4998
3.0000    0.3748
4.0000    0.2710
5.0000    0.1900
6.0000    0.1240
7.0000    0.0815
8.0000    0.0494
9.0000    0.0297
10.0000    0.0168
```